# Button with full width of the page inline with the others

Tags: html, css

I have 3 buttons, and the first 2 buttons must have a fixed width and the third button should take full width of the page, but it must be inline with the other two buttons..
Something like this:

---btn1--- ---btn2--- -------------------------------btn3-----------------------------------------

I tried something but it didn't worked because the third button is going to the next line and taking the all size of the screen.

HTML:

```
<div class="banner">
<button class="btn1">First button</button>
<button class="btn2">Second button</button>
<button class="btn3">Third button</button>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.btn3 {
    width:100%;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/cabjcur2/embedded/result/

Comment: if you give 100% width for 3rd button, then how it fit in the same line ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the calc function from css

```
.btn1 {
   float: left;
   width: 200px;
}
.btn2 {
   float: left;
   width: 200px;
}
.btn3 {
   float: left;
   width: calc(100% - 400px);
}
```

see this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/3c2nf67m/

Browser support: http://caniuse.com/#search=calc

Comment: Thanks! I must remember this function :D

Comment: do you know how this function must be implemented in stylus? Or if it works with stylus?

Answer (score 0):

You need to define `width` for others button as well. And distribute the width `%` between them.

```
.btn1 {
    width:15%;
}

.btn2 {
    width:15%;
}


.btn3 {
    width:60%;
}
```

If  others buttons need fixed `width`, covert pixel to `%` or backwards.

Comment: The other 2 buttons must have a fixed width in pixels, and the third button must take the rest of blank space

Comment: I'm wondering if this could be made only in css, or it also needs some jquery code

Comment: @Valeriu92 Ok,  If  the others button need fixed width, covert pixel to `%` or backwards.

Answer (score 0):

```
.btn3 {
    width:80%;
}
```

Adjust the width percentage, give it a max / min width % e.g max-width: 80%; min-width: 30%;

Do this until it fits your needs for your site

Answer (score 0):

Button width of 100% will take the full screen. But you already have two buttons inline there and hence to get the full screen width it goes to the next line.

I tried out this piece of CSS without changing anything else :

```
 .btn3 {
     width: 80%;
  }
```

Worked properly as you were expecting .

FIddle : http://jsfiddle.net/xfaknxux/ . 
However bear in mind, this code piece does not take screen re changing into account. It works only for a full screen .

Comment: @Valeriu92 : Yes it will not. But the question seemed like the OP is always expecting a full sized screen in the browser. In those instances it will work .